# How to show upcoming appointments in Outlook 2010 for 2 or 3 months ahead in time in the To Do Bar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

How to make Outlook show next upcoming appointments for 2 or 3 months ahead in time in the To Do Bar?

It only shows 1 month ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it based on dates. It's simply the number of appointments that you can set. Right-click in the header of the TO-Do Bar and click Options. 
On the dialog box you can change the number of appointments.

Answer (score 0):

This is tied to the number of months you have displayed, which by default is 1.

If you have no Appointment set within the month, it won't display. You can adjust the number of months you want to display; however screen real estate will quickly become a problem.

**Go to View** --> **To-Do Bar** --> **Options** --> **Number of month rows**

Comment: Not with me. I have 3 months that show, but can only see appointments 1 month ahead.